# C Pass Dynamic Array to Function

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
void word(FILE*fptr, char sender[]);

void dosya(){
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("com.txt","r");

    int c, i, sendno=0, receiveno=0;
    char d, e, send, space1, space2, receive;

    char* sender = malloc(sizeof(char));
    while(send != ' '){                     /*read sender's name*/
        send = getc(fp1);
        if(send == ' ')
            break;
        else{
            sender[sendno] = send;
            sendno++;
            sender = (char *) realloc(sender, (sendno+1)*sizeof(char));
        }
     }
     e = getc(fp1);    /* read # character  */

     word(fp1, sender);
     fclose(fp1);

}

void word(FILE*fptr, char sender[]){
     printf("%s", sender);
}

// Driver program to test above functions./
int main()
{
     dosya();
     return 0;
}
```

I create a dynamic array called sender with malloc and realloc it every time i read a letter, it stops when letter is space character. I want to use this array in another function. How can i reach it in word function?

Comment: it seems correct syntax. What is the error that you get

Comment: Sorry my problem was about something else. I was thinking about the wrong part. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Several issue in your code, like using `send` before initializing it, assigning `realloc` return to `sender` (think about the case when `realloc` will fail), allocated memory never freed, what if `fopen` fails due to some reason.. etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

`getc()` has no clear indication of `EOF(=end of file)` state, making it loop indefinitely if no whitespace character is present within your file. Which in turn is why your print function gets never called.

There are several other issues which make your code pretty hard to read, which is why it might be so hard to debug.

I would therefore suggest that you rework your program in the following way:

1. create a separate function that checks wether or not the file exists
2. use meaningful variable declarations and dont declare variables that you do not use
3. use fgets or similar to read the file line by line and then loop through your buffer searching for a whitespace character or eof.
4. `realloc()` for every character is redundant, instead count characters within your loop and then dynamically create an array with malloc & save your input with `strncpy`/`memcpy` or similar

**Code:**

```
    int Exists(const char *path)
{
    if (fopen(path, "r") == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    fclose();
    return 1;
}
    void ReadLine(const char *path)
{
    if (Exists(path) == -1)
    {
        printf("file doesnt exist \n");
    }
    else
    {
        char buffer[256];
        FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
        char *key = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        int n = 0;
        while (fgets(buffer, 255, fp) != NULL) // read file till newline/255 c limit
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(char); i++)
            {
                if (buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i] == '\n')
                {
                    if (i > (strlen(key)))
                    {
                        (char*)realloc(key, i * sizeof(char));
                    }
                    strncpy(key, buffer, i);
                    key[i] = '\0';
                    break;
                }
            }
            //key now holds value of words separated by whitespace or newline character
        }
    }
fclose();
free(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `void dosya()` prototype into `char *dosya()`. Return allocated `sender` to `main()`, store it in variable, send to `word()` and free allocated memory after all.

Like this:

```
char *dosya() {
    // ...
    // collect data
    // ...

    return sender;
}

//...

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char *p;
    // ...
    // open file for fptr
    //
    if (fptr == NULL)
        return -1;

    p = dosya();

    if (p != NULL) {
        word(fptr, p);
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Do not forget to check `malloc()` and `realloc()` return value for `NULL` (insufficient memory);
- Do not forget to add `'\0'` delimiter at end of `sender` after all required characters stored;
- `realloc()` for every character is very inefficient way but it is outside of original question.